# What is wrong with localised questions?

Tags: discussion

Localised questions are banned, but why? What justification is there for requiring questions to be geographically applicable to everyone, but not requiring them to be stylistically applicable to everyone?

Someone could ask a question about Chow Gar or Feng Shou that never gets answered because hardly anyone practices it, just as a question about instruction in Moosejaw could be unanswered because nobody else on SE happens to live there. The separation is entirely arbitrary, and the site already is lacking in questions, it doesn't make sense to limit questions that one person might be able to answer just because another person can't.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/54/what-style-schools-are-there-in-location

Answer (score 2):

It's not about whether the question is answered, it's about how applicable the question is to another person reading the question after the fact.

See [What questions should be closed with reason "too localized"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized)

Note that *this absolutely **does** allow for* questions such as "the only martial arts around me are X and Y. What I want in a martial art is Z. What should I do?" The question, as discussed in meta.stackoverflow, is definitely localized. It's also definitely not *too* localized: other people are likely to face similar (or even nearly identical) situations, and would benefit from seeing the reasoning that comes with answers to that specific question.

For instance, the question that I think triggered this question was [this](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1384/choosing-form-of-martial-art). The OP has an option between karate and TKD. Do we know exactly what these schools do? No. But we can make a pretty good guess that the karate school doesn't wear judogis and spend 90% of their time on tai-otoshi, harai-goshi, and osotogari. We can give answers that are extremely useful not just to this person, but to the myriad other people who have a specific reason to diligently avoid concussions and are faced with the choice of not training, training in karate, and training in TKD. Most of making a good answer involves telling the OP **what to ask, what to watch out for, and what to expect** when they check out the school.

I think it's a localized question, but certainly not too localized.

Comment: "It's not about whether the question is answered, it's about how applicable the question is to another person reading the question after the fact" - that was my point with the Chow Gar or Feng Shou examples. Anyone else reading the question won't get anything out of it.